# Changing text based on the final letter of user name

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, slim

In my system, users will register their names. In the natural language the system is used with, names end differently depending its use, such as:

- who: `"name surname"`
- with who: `"namai surnamai"`

Due to this, I need to change the ending of `@provider_user.name` in some places; if it ends with `e`, replace `e` with `ai`.

My HTML slim code is:

```
= render partial: 'services/partials/messages/original_message', locals: { header: t('html.text.consultation_with.for_provider', name: @provider_user.name)
```

It takes text from a yml file and uses `@provider_user.name`.

Any suggestions to work this around?

Comment: `string.sub(/e$/, 'ai')` would substitute a trailing `e` with `ai`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, simple single line code

```
@provider_user.name.split.map {|w| (w.end_with?('e') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'ai') : w) }.join(" ")
```

I am sure, it will convert `"name surname"` to `"namai surnamai"`.

In additional cases...

```
@provider_user.name.split.map {|w| (w.end_with?('e') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'ai') : (w.end_with?('us') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'mi') : (w.end_with?('i') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'as') : w))) }.join(" ")
```

Comment: Thank you Vijay, that worked as well. Additional question - how can it be extended for more options like: "e = ai, us = mi, i = as" on the same record?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but solution for multiple options doesn't seem to work. It throw "something went wrong" error when it tries the second option (in my case when I have user name ending with "us")

Comment: Hi Vijay, would you be able to review the code for multiple options. It looks convenient, but doesn't seem to be working. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
"name surname".gsub(/e\b/, 'ai') # "namai surnamai"
```

`.gsub` uses a regular expression to search and replace in a string. Its the greedy version of `.sub` meaning that it will replace all occurrences.

`\b` matches any word boundry.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Additional question - how can it be extended for more options like: "e = ai, us = mi, i = as" on the same record?

Comment: can you please suggest how it can be used for multiple options - that would help me a lot.

Comment: I think its better that you ask a new question as its quite a bit different than your original question

Comment: thanks, created new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633649/changing-text-based-on-the-final-letter-of-user-name-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy, that's why I love Ruby...

```
class String
    def replace_ends(replace, with) 
        end_array = self.split " "
        end_array.map! do |var|
            break unless var.end_with? replace
            var.chomp(" ").chomp(replace) + with
        end
        return end_array.join " "
    end
end
```

Comment: Want to try this option. In what file do you suggest I should define it?

Comment: I don't know, but it won't break the String class if you do it in the file you are going to be putting it in. Imma just gonna make it replace all ends.

Comment: done making it work properly it should work like var = var.replace_ends "11","12" btw i've debbuged it in jruby so hmu on any issues