# Changing text based on the final letter of user name using regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

I am looking to change the ending of the user name based on the use case (in the language system will operate, names ends depending on how it is used).

So need to define all endings of names and define the replacement for them.
Was suggested to use .gsub regular expression to search and replace in a string:

[Changing text based on the final letter of user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595868/changing-text-based-on-the-final-letter-of-user-name)

```
"name surname".gsub(/e\b/, 'ai')
```

this will replace e with ai, so "name surname = namai surnamai".

How can it be used for more options like: "e = ai, us = mi, i = as" on the same record?

thanks

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/W7XPjo

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if there are keys with overlap on right hand side, for ex: `e` and `er`, need to ensure the longer length key comes first... `Regexp.union(h.keys.sort_by { |w| -w.length })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `String#gsub` with block. [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) say:

> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

So you can use a regex with concatenation of all substrings to be replaced and then replace it in the block, e.g. using a hash that maps matches to replacements.

Full example:

```
replacements = {'e'=>'ai', 'us'=>'mi', 'i' => 'as'}
['surname', 'surnamus', 'surnami'].map do |s| 
  s.gsub(/(e|us|i)$/){|p| replacements[p] }
end
```

Comment: `sub` and `gsub` also allow hash as replacement argument.. so you can use `s.gsub(/(e|us|i)$/, replacements)`

Comment: thanks. In what file that should be defined? I am working on HTML.SLIM, so the peace of code I shared is used in html.slim. Is there a way it can be configured soly in that html.slim file?

Comment: I would define this in the model or in a helper as you should avoid placing complex logic in your views. This also makes it much easier to test.

Comment: @max @mrzasa still not getting it work for multiple records. What I have now in provider_helper.rb is: 

`module ProvidersHelper

  def replacements = {'e'=>'ai', 'us'=>'mi', 'i' => 'as'}
    ['surname', 'surnamus', 'surnami'].map do |s|
    s.gsub(/(e|us|i)$/){|p| replacements[p] }
  end
end` 

 And then in html.slim - before I had `name: @provider_user.name,` now I am trying to use helper: `replacements(@provider_user.name),`

also the user names comes from the user input, so isnt this line makes putting user names in the code: `[‘surname', 'surnamus', 'surnami'].map do |s|` ?

Comment: It's just an example, you need to replace the hardcoded strings with your real surnames

Comment: @mrzasa yes, but it is not known what surnames user will register with, I know only the endings (there are only few ending options like us, as, a that are used in the surnames of the language system will operate in ). So should I specify only endings? `[‘as', 'us', 'a'].map do |s|` or should I leave it blank `[‘', '', ''].map do |s|` ? Can you also suggest if I am using the helper wrongly in html.slim file?

Comment: You need to pass the surname entered by user. I cannot suggest you anything more withotu knowing the structure of your app. This seems to be another topic, you ask for this in another question.

Comment: It would be better to construct your regex from the hash `replacements`, so that if the latter changes you don't have to manually change your regex. Also, the use of `gsub` might be confusing to the reader considering that at most one string replacement will be performed. I suggest using `sub` instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Sundeep makes an important observation in a comment on the question. If, for example, the substitutions were give by the following hash:

```
g = {'e'=>'ai', 's'=>'es', 'us'=>'mi', 'i' => 'as'}
  #=> {"e"=>"ai", "s"=>"es", "us"=>"mi", "i"=>"as"}
```

`'surnamus'` would be converted (incorrectly) to `'surnamues'` merely because `'s'=>'es'` precedes `'us'=>'mi'` in `g`. That situation may not exist at present, but it may be prudent to allow for it in future, particularly because it is so simple to do so:

```
h = g.sort_by { |k,_| -k.size }.to_h
  #=> {"us"=>"mi", "e"=>"ai", "s"=>"es", "i"=>"as"}

arr = ['surname', 'surnamus', 'surnami', 'surnamo']
```

The substitutions can be done using the form of [String@#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-sub) that employs a hash as its second argument.

```
r = /#{Regexp.union(h.keys)}\z/
  #=> /(?-mix:us|e|s|i)\z/i
arr.map { |s| s.sub(r,h) }
  #=> ["surnamai", "surnammi", "surnamas", "surnamo"]
```

See also [Regexp::union](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union).

Incidentally, though key-insertion order has been guaranteed for hashes since Ruby v1.9, there is a continuing debate as to whether that property should be made use of in Ruby code, mainly because there was no concept of key order when hashes were first used in computer programs. This answer provides a good example of the benefit of exploiting key order.