# Replacing few strings at the end of a user name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, slim-lang

Using this piece of code in html.slim view file to change ending of a name from `e` to `ai`, and it works fine:

`@provider_user.name.split.map {|w| (w.end_with?('e') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'ai') : w) }.join(" ")`

And using this pease for multiple options:

`@provider_user.name.split.map {|w| (w.end_with?('e') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'ai') : (w.end_with?('d') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'i') : (w.end_with?('as') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'u') : w))) }.join(" ")`

All good when only last string needs to be changed, like `name = namai, namd = nami` .

However for `(w.end_with?('as') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 1]) + 'u')` i get `namas = namau`, instead of `namas = namu` .

Guess it is due to `length - 1` which makes a replacement of last string only.

How can it be adjusted to replace more that last string?

Comment: Use the tips from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633649/changing-text-based-on-the-final-letter-of-user-name-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chomp with the last two characters

```
w.end_with?('as') ? (w.chomp(w[w.length - 2, 2]) + 'u'
```

Note that `w.length - 2` positions to the second to last character, and the `, 2` indicates you want two characters, not one.